# JavaScript function not firing from button click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following html:

```
    <input type="text" id="theInput" />

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Search" onclick="testFunction(document.getElementById('theInput').value)" /><br>
```

I am trying to trigger this:

```
function testFunction(data)
{
    alert(data);
}
```

I also tried an alternative, using:

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = testFunction(document.getElementById("theInput").value);
```

Sadly, neither of these methods seem to get the function to trigger.  I'm sure I am missing something simple, could anyone point it out, please?

Comment: ur missing value attr in input

Comment: 2nd option is wrong... onclick = handler;.... the handler has to be a function reference whereas you are setting the returned value of testFunction that will be undefined in your case.
use onclick=function(){/*testFunction execution code*/};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have test and found that your code is OK, you can see the [demo here](http://jsbin.com/oguxaz/1/). However, I think it not work in your page because of the way you include your javascript functions. You have better to put all scripts in the `head` tag of the page.

If you use some framework, make sure your functions and bindings are executed when all javascript loaded.

Comment: It works for me, also, once I abstract it.  In the larger code I am trying to work with, it's not firing.  It's infuriating.  But nice to know the logic was right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `onclick`, which only allows you to add a single click handler to the element, you should use addEventListener which allows you to register multiple listeners.  See below:

```
document.getElementById('clickMe').addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert(document.getElementById('theInput').value);
});
```

JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3rjcE/)